# Cannot find symbol DataBindingComponent on Android Studio 3.2 Canary 16 Kotlin project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I just created a new project on Android Studio 3.2 Canary 16 with Kotlin enabled. Then I also enabled data binding, but I'm getting an error saying that it could not find the DataBindingComponent class.

Here's my project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    ext.android_plugin_version = '3.2.0-alpha10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha16'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My module gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.julianonunes.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.2"
}
```

My activity's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="data"
            type="net.julianonunes.myapp.RegisterData" />
    </data>

    ....
</layout>
```

And here's the build output:

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :app
app: 'annotationProcessor' dependencies won't be recognized as kapt annotation processors. Please change the configuration name to 'kapt' for these artifacts: 'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.2.0-alpha16'.

> Task :clean
> Task :app:clean
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug
> Task :app:processDebugResources
> Task :app:generateDebugSources
> Task :app:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDebug
> Task :app:transformDataBindingBaseClassLogWithDataBindingMergeGenClassesForDebug
> Task :app:transformDataBindingWithDataBindingMergeArtifactsForDebug
> Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug
Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.1.2/compiler-3.1.2.pom
Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.1.2/compiler-3.1.2.jar
> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin
e: /home/juliano/Documents/Projetos/myapp/app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug/out/net/julianonunes/myapp/databinding/ActivityMainBinding.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
  protected ActivityMainBinding(DataBindingComponent _bindingComponent, View _root,
                                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class ActivityMainBinding
e: /home/juliano/Documents/Projetos/myapp/app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug/out/net/julianonunes/myapp/databinding/ActivityMainBinding.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot, @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                                                                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class ActivityMainBinding
e: /home/juliano/Documents/Projetos/myapp/app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug/out/net/julianonunes/myapp/databinding/ActivityMainBinding.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class ActivityMainBinding
e: /home/juliano/Documents/Projetos/myapp/app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug/out/net/julianonunes/myapp/databinding/ActivityMainBinding.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class ActivityMainBinding
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.onHandleStep(ProcessExpressions.java:77)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.runStep(ProcessDataBinding.java:203)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.access$000(ProcessDataBinding.java:188)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.doProcess(ProcessDataBinding.java:90)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:65)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:131)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:87)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:45)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:257)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:212)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:95)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:374)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:365)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:130)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:161)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:405)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:920)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:950)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:919)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:404)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor91.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 8s
20 actionable tasks: 19 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

What is wrong with my project?

PS: The problem also happens on Android Studio 3.1.2

Comment: For me the true error was actually printed after this. After fixing that error, this one goes away as well.

Comment: In my case no other error was shown in log, but after reviewing my diffs I found an unimported annotation in some kt file. After fixing import, build works. Seems to be some problem in kapt processor.

Comment: Cannot find symbol DataBindingComponent when build from command line using ./gradlew assembleDebug

Comment: `android.databinding.enableV2=false

android.enableExperimentalFeatureDatabinding = false`. adding this to `grade.properties` solved my problem

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Databinding libraries are being refactored as a part of androidx refactoring.

I found the databinding annotation processor dependency link from google's maven repository [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.databinding/databinding-compiler/3.2.0-alpha16).

I've constructed the actual gradle dependency from there.

```
kapt "androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.2.0-alpha16"
```

**Update**
As of Android studio 3.2.0-beta01, databinding no longer needs its annotation processor dependency to be declared in the gradle file, since databinding is capable of resolving its dependency.

In the latest versions of Android Studio you just to enable the databinding/viewbinding in the gradle file of the app module.

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
    dataBinding true
}
```

Comment: I have removed this dependency and tried all below solution but nothing seems to be working

Comment: What studio version are you using?

Comment: Android studio 3.3 Canary 11 with gradle 4.10

Comment: Error : cannot find symbol DataBindingComponent, I hava data binding enable to ture in gradle, I don't know what's the problem

Comment: Enabled DataBinding in the gradle?

Comment: I have enabled it in gradle, I have follow everything in https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start

Comment: Thanks you save me from disaster, at last my issue solved with your solution,  i have used 
kapt "androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.2.0"
Gradle version and binding version should be same

Comment: @habibullah for use of "androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.2.0", it required to enable androidX into gradle properties. Because i tried but your solution but still getting same issue

Comment: Just erasing the kapt ... line in the dependency section of the gradle file solved the problem for me as well. (Android Studio 3.3)

Comment: thanks and awesome, this fixed my issue as well (AS 3.2.1) @SamuelRobert

Comment: id 'kotlin-kapt'  i remove this line from plugins ,, and now the error disappeared.

Answer (score 64):

With the following setup

> Android Studio 3.2.1 Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October
>   8, 2018 JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 x86_64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit
>   Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o macOS 10.13.3

And DataBinding simply enable by having this in my app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

and then

```
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

and also this in my gradle.wrapper properties

```
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

I had the same errors:

```
could not find the DataBindingComponent class.
```

I had more than 100 of them. It turned out that those errors were not important and that the true underlying error was not showed by the IDE. Therefore, I increased the number of errors that the Kotlin compiler can display by adding this in build.gradle:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
kapt {
        javacOptions {
            // Increase the max count of errors from annotation processors.
            // Default is 100.
            option("-Xmaxerrs", 500)
        }
    }
```

An suddenly, right below all those fake errrors, I saw the real one caused by a failed merge conflict resolution

Comment: Hi, how do I do this in a java project?

Comment: bunch of fake errors initially to Do with DataBindingComponent. then when i increase error size. I saw it was an issue with me using the incorrect scope with dagger.

Comment: This was the only solution which worked..Thanks a lot..it helped.

Comment: Cannot find symbol DataBindingComponent while build from command line using ./gradlew assembleDebug

Comment: I spend days in my life to search errors without messages...! Thanks mate, you are the man of the year :-D

Comment: Can't believe this is still an issue on 1/10/2019. It should have something like [For More errors click here]. Thanks man

Comment: The trick with the option("-Xmaxerrs", 500) did it. Couldn't see the correct error as it wasn't even shown. Thank you!

Comment: I am stuck here too so sad.

Comment: ya, found the actual error in the middle, in my case, it was a query issue in room db. Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

Just delete the compiler dependency (kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$gradleVersion), that worked for me. Apparently, it is provided with binding plugin from 3.2.0.

Answer (score 24):

Same Error here on Android Studio 3.3.1, no Kotlin, pure Java, using androidx

build.gradle contains

```
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
```

gradle.properties contains

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

I've been fighting the issue for hours and then solved it as follows:

Temporarily declare an empty interface for DataBindingComponent in your Project (in `src/main/java/androidx.databinding/DataBindingComponent.java`)

```
package androidx.databinding;

public interface DataBindingComponent {
}
```

Let it compile and the error will be gone. But now the actual root error will be revealed. The one that was actually causing all the trouble but was somehow swallowed. In my case it was coming from AutoValue indicating that i was using it incorrectly

```
error: Parameter type java.lang.Boolean of setter method should be boolean to match getter
```

fixing that and then removing the dummy interface makes the compiler happy again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I have struggled a lot because of this issue.

Comment: OMG, thank you, thank you, thank you. This worked!! thank you! I was migrating to androidx and in the final stages, after finishing, i had like 70 errors like OP. Your trick revealed 13 underlying errors. Did I say thank you? :D

Comment: It is Android Studio 3.6.1 now. Still need to follow this trick to see the actual error. :(

Comment: This is great!  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It saved my time. Keep up the good work @Ginie

Answer (score 23):

If You're already using **Android Studio 3.2** stable version, Just remove the dependency, it's already included.

Comment: Solved it for me, thank you. They should have added a tooltip/autofix in the IDE.

Comment: Double up for this. My error was a little different but this was the root cause. In case someone googles for it: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
  at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.onHandleStep(ProcessExpressions.java:77)
  at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.runStep(ProcessDataBinding.java:203)
  at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.access$000(ProcessDataBinding.java:188)
...`

Answer (score 16):

For what it’s worth, I had a similar issue and it was the result of a bad Room query that was related to a data binding.

Comment: works for me, I disabled typeconverter for check and it worked

Comment: Thanks! I had an issue regarding Room too. I was using `ArrayList` as a return to a query where it has to be a `List`.

Comment: This is bad. An entirely unrelated issue in room causes this issue.

Comment: This is NOT exclusive to Room. Any other annotation processor that you use can throw an exception during compilation, failing before DataBinding processor comes in play.

Comment: and that error remained buried in between the error stated as the question.

Answer (score 15):

In my case it was a bad dagger annotation. I put custom scope on a Module instead of putting it on a provides method.

`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: I had a missing import statement for an annotation value and method parameter. With Dagger 2.19 I got the databinding nonsense above. Luckily Dagger 2.21 pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue.

Changing `Kapt` to `annotationProcessor` only for DataBinding fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I removed the dependency and it works too.

Answer (score 7):

i face this problem when updating to android studio 3.2 , i change gradle plugin from 3.2.0 to 3.1.4 and it works fine 
 --> i think it's a gradle problem , it will be updated for sure very soon

Comment: try to change the gradle and to remove 
 kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.2"

Comment: I am not at all using  kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.2", but I figured out the problem, it was due to the wrong package structure and moving files from one folder to another

Answer (score 6):

Dagger may also be the cause. <del>Changing dagger version from 2.17 back to 2.16 can fix this problem for now.</del>

Discussion: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1245

<del>**Update**</del>

<del>Dagger 2.18 is out but unfortunately it still won't work after I tested(Have I missed something?).</del>

<del>**Update2**</del>

<del>Dagger 2.19 also won't work and the discussion is locked.</del>

<del>But [in the google issuetracke](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115738511#comment6), there're solutions/workarounds. I tested and they worked. Check it if you want to use the latest Dagger.</del>

**Update3**

Dagger problem has been fixed in the Android Studio 3.3.

Comment: I am also pretty sure that it is caused by Dagger2 in my/our case. The official documentation of DataBindingComponent even mentions dagger: "If using Dagger 2, the developer should extend this interface and annotate the extended interface as a Component." (source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingComponent). But I don't understand exactly what to do here and if it will fix the error.

Comment: @muetzenflo Your info seems promising. I'll try to extend that component and see if it can fix the error.

Comment: @muetzenflo I've tried the solution but it didn't work. I guess it only takes effects when the app is running but the problem happens in the compile time.

Comment: 2.19 is out and the issue is still there

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk You're right. But I found some workaround in the issuetracker. Check the updated answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 5):

My issue was that I tried to enable data binding for my `Login` module but not the `App` module. After adding:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

to the `App` module and removed it from the `Login` module, it worked.

Comment: You sir, saved my career in self-employment. It was like trial and error for > 8 hours. I gotta say though, I was just missing "buildFeatures.dataBinding = true" in App module. Had to set the same for all feature modules as well. May your life always be filled with honey and milk.

Answer (score 4):

i finally fixed my problem because i was using **Android Annotations** and they released a new **Version 4.5.1** 1 Hour ago, where they support Grade Plugin 3.2.0.

I was searching for this bug for a week and i´m happy now. Hope this helps you, too!

Answer (score 4):

In my case I enabled data binding in dynamic feature module only. After I enabled data binding in root module, error disappeared.

From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start#build_environment):

> Note: You must configure data binding for app modules that depend on libraries that use data binding, even if the app module doesn't directly use data binding.

Also you may need to invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: Thank you! It was impossible to figure this out from the error message. Nice find!

Answer (score 3):

I solved the error by adding

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in my project's gradle.properties file

Comment: Didn't work for me. What does the above do? Where did you find it?

Comment: @auval  
    `android.useAndroidX:` When set to `true`, this flag indicates that you want to start using AndroidX from now on. If the flag is absent, Android Studio behaves as if the flag were set to `false`.
    `android.enableJetifier:` When set to `true`, this flag indicates that you want to have tool support (from the Android Gradle plugin) to automatically convert existing third-party libraries as if they were written for AndroidX. If the flag is absent, Android Studio behaves as if the flag were set to `false`.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I am using Android studio 3.3 these parameters are already present

Comment: This is definitely required if you migrate to Android X and use databinding etc. I migrated on one machine but the error appeared on a different one because gradle.properties is not in source control

Answer (score 3):

Just remove kapt "com.android.databinding..." dependency. If you are using Android Studio 3.2 or greater version.

Answer (score 3):

In my case,
If your using Dynamic Feature Module :

> build.gradle(app)

```
dataBinding {
    enabled true
}
```

This needs to enabled on both root and child gradle files (don't forget to add kapt plugin).

Comment: THANNNNKKKKKK YOOOOOUUUUUUUU FFS

Comment: @zeromod Can you please add which kapt plugin? Also, what if I don't have kotlin in my project?

Answer (score 3):

Please add this line in gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta05'`
with and without explicit dependency `kapt "androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.3.0-alpha06"`

And still getting the same exception.

I have also tried 3.3.0-alpha06 but nothing changed.

**UPDATE:**
After 2 days, I resolved the issue.
What I did is, manually fixing all the files that had problems, because of *Migration to AndroidX* (wrong packages in imports and XMLs etc.). Additionally, I needed to update Glide from 4.7 to 4.8. When I fixed all red files the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

This is my most stupid mistake!
I have actually created a private variable for Databinding and that was causing this issue.

Just use a `lateinit var binding` and  it Worked.

This could help someone!

Comment: This solved the issue with me. Thanks! Took me 2 hours to find this and didn't scroll down far enough to see your comment. :(

Comment: Glad this helped you! Databinding errors are hard to interpret !!

Answer (score 2):

For me, there was an error in my layout file. I referenced a function that was non-existent.

`android:text="@{() -> sleepTrackerViewModel.nightStrings}"`

Below is the solution:

`android:text="@{sleepTrackerViewModel.nightStrings}"`

Answer (score 1):

I fix it updating [Android Studio to Canary 16](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/) AND this in gradle.wrapper.properties `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.7-all.zip`

Comment: I'm already using Canary 16 and Gradle 4.7, but it is not working.

Comment: I'm using Android studio 3.3 Canary 11 and Gradle 4.10, and I am getting the error, so this solution dosen't do for me

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue **was resolved** by changing:

```
androidExtensions.experimental = true
```

(i.e. gradle DSL as a one-liner)

to

```
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

apart from `could not find the DataBindingComponent class` I also had `error: incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation` associated with `kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize` annotation (@Parcelize)

Android Studio 3.3; gradle-4.10.1-all; tools.build:gradle 3.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue when I was importing class in databinding, that did not exist. Also use

```
allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "1000"
        }
    }
}
```

for recieving all error messages to find the issue. For my project it was limited to 50.

Answer (score 0):

Something else to try :) I was trying to get the GithubBrowserSample into Android Studio 3.2 (RC3). I kept getting lots of weird errors on databinding even though it doesn't specify data binding versions in the main build.gradle. The solution was to **remove these two lines** from the gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4536m
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

Answer (score 0):

My situation:

> Android Studio v3.2.1
>
> com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1
>
> https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip

I found that by removing databinding from my layout, recompiling the app and then adding the databinding back in it fixed this issue.

I changed the `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(...)` to just `setContentView(...)` and reduced my activity layout to the bare minimum:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Then add the databinding back in piece by piece.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was an **import error** in one of the files. Simply opening that file made imports to happen automatically and thereafter project got built.

It's a pity, that AS gave zero indication to this, neither did error stacktrace.

In case nothing from posted answer helps - just surf through all the files in the project and seek for a file which has incorrect import statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in jetifier. Here's a workaround for now until the next update. Put this in your project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta02'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dataroom library, check @Dao annotation in your DAO classes.
In my case, I forgot to add @Dao to my interface of RoomDatabase'Dao.

Answer (score 0):

Build errors for generated interfaces like `DataBindingComponent` are usually misleading. Try to look for any other build errors and fix those first, then recompile.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove following import from Gradle,

```
androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha06
```

Even though its weird issue, Just try to remove to un necessary imports, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If using with Room Database, check all your Dao classes if you have any import issue or not specified required TypeConverter using `@TypeConverters` , this error is misleading, and should be fixed if you update project level gradle build tools version to latest.
I used `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'` and got error correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For my case there was some error in Room database Item class...
Error was about private modifier which should be public for member variables of Room db item class.

Use and explore command line **./gradlew assembleDebug** to see stacktrace.

**#Room #Database #Table class #DAO**

Answer (score 0):

In latest versions, no need of adding  dependency like this
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.0-alpha16".
Just adding:

```
buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
```

is sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

this is my solution

implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifeCycleExtensionVersion"

change

implementation "**androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx**:$lifeCycleExtensionVersion"