# Issue with data binding with gradle 3.2.1

Tags: android, android-databinding

When i have updated android studios 3.2.0 to 3.2.1. I have use data binding, when run project show me error like this, if i am wrong please suggest me.

```
Could not find com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.1.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Users/Taufiq/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.pom
file:/C:/Users/Taufiq/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.jar
file:/C:/Users/Taufiq/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.pom
file:/C:/Users/Taufiq/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.jar
file:/C:/Users/Taufiq/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.pom
file:/C:/Users/Taufiq/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.jar
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.pom
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.jar     
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.jar
```

Required by:
    project :app

project.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext{
        kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
        gradle_version = '3.2.1'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.taufik.kotlinbindingtest"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$gradle_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

If i am wrong please suggest me.

Comment: disable gradle offline work from settings of android studio.

Comment: @Jeel Vankhede i have already disabled offline work.

Comment: use this `android.databinding.enableV2=true` instead of `dataBinding { enabled = true }` & remove implicit annotationProcessor.

Comment: when adding `android.databinding.enableV2=true`  its show me error like this `Could not get unknown property 'databinding' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.`

Comment: i got it please remove this `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$gradle_version"` from app.gradle

Comment: @Taufik's comment/solution here worked for me! I was importing from an older project and I guess this kapt is no longer required with gradle 3.2.1. I was able to build and run the project...BUT there might still be issues. If so, I'll post here.

Comment: @Mike Critchley, May i know that what is the error you see?

Comment: @Taufik Same problem as the OP. The project didn't build when I specifically added the kapt ... in the dependencies. Removing it solved the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find symbol DataBindingComponent on Android Studio 3.2 Canary 16 Kotlin project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594507/cannot-find-symbol-databindingcomponent-on-android-studio-3-2-canary-16-kotlin-p)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I looked for many solution and finally i found that problem was in one of Dependencies, So I removed this `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$gradle_version"` from app.gradle and project run succeffully.

Comment: this works thank you. can someone please explain this!

Comment: I also had to remove `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` line too.

Comment: apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' but when you delete this plugin, you can not use bindingAdapter also such as BR

Answer (score 4):

The answer is pretty simple:

just **add** these lines in gradle app

```
//Data binding
dataBinding.enabled = true
```

and **remove** these two lines :

```
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
 kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$gradle_version"
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Android Studio 3.2, this kapt plugin is no longer required.

However, without this plug in, the error message in case of any error, while compiling is cryptic. 
So, only option now it seems now is to downgrade your Gradle version to 3.1.4.

Thanks to article at http://mobiledevhub.com/2018/01/05/android-two-way-databinding/