# Android - Build fails with databinding and kapt with gradle 3.2.1

Tags: android, kotlin, build, kapt

I'm facing a problem with databinding and kapt
I am using kotlin with Android Studio 3.2.1 
The problem is when I use kapt (which I have to use I think if I want to use DBFlow), the build fails.

I have tried several solutions I found like invalidating caches and restarting or cleaning the project and rebuilding it, adding or deleting kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4' 
but it is apparently useless to add it with the recent versions of kapt

Here is the gradle file of the project

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    ext.dbflow_version = '4.2.4'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And the gradle file of the app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "paf.songrecorder"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }

    kapt {
        generateStubs = true
    }

}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "com.github.raizlabs.dbflow:dbflow-processor:$dbflow_version"
    kapt "com.github.raizlabs.dbflow:dbflow-processor:$dbflow_version"

    implementation "com.github.raizlabs.dbflow:dbflow-core:$dbflow_version"
    implementation "com.github.raizlabs.dbflow:dbflow:$dbflow_version"
    implementation "com.github.raizlabs.dbflow:dbflow-kotlinextensions:$dbflow_version"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

When the app is building it can't find in the DataBinderMapperImpl class the BindingImpl classes

[Edit]

I have this error without adding the line :

```
import paf.songrecorder.databinding.SongBindingImpl; ^ symbol: class SongBindingImpl location: package paf.songrecorder.databinding – PAF 11 mins ago
```

And after adding 
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_plugin_version" :

Do you have any idea of what could be the cause of this issue?

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kapt'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:944)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1600(DefaultConfiguration.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:918)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:415)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getFiles(CompositeFileCollection.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.SubpluginUtilsKt$withWrappedKaptOptions$1.apply(subpluginUtils.kt:71)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.SubpluginUtilsKt$withWrappedKaptOptions$1.apply(subpluginUtils.kt)
    at java.util.HashMap.compute(HashMap.java:1196)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.SubpluginUtilsKt.withWrappedKaptOptions(subpluginUtils.kt:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptGenerateStubsTask.setupCompilerArgs(KaptGenerateStubsTask.kt:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptGenerateStubsTask.setupCompilerArgs(KaptGenerateStubsTask.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAware$DefaultImpls.setupCompilerArgs$default(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareKt.prepareCompilerArguments(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAware$DefaultImpls.getFilteredArgumentsMap(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareWithInput$DefaultImpls.getFilteredArgumentsMap(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompileTool.getFilteredArgumentsMap(Tasks.kt:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptGenerateStubsTask_Decorated.getFilteredArgumentsMap(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.DefaultPropertyWalker$DefaultPropertyValue$1$1.create(DefaultPropertyWalker.java:90)
    at org.gradle.util.SingleMessageLogger.whileDisabled(SingleMessageLogger.java:240)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.DefaultPropertyWalker$DefaultPropertyValue$1.get(DefaultPropertyWalker.java:87)
    at com.google.common.base.Suppliers$MemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:125)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.DefaultPropertyWalker$DefaultPropertyValue.getValue(DefaultPropertyWalker.java:139)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.DefaultPropertyWalker$DefaultPropertyValue.validate(DefaultPropertyWalker.java:150)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputPropertySpec.validate(DefaultTaskInputPropertySpec.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.DefaultTaskProperties.validate(DefaultTaskProperties.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:47)
    ... 103 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/PAF/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.pom
    file:/C:/Users/PAF/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.jar
    file:/C:/Users/PAF/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.pom
    file:/C:/Users/PAF/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.jar
    file:/C:/Users/PAF/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.pom
    file:/C:/Users/PAF/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.jar
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.pom
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.jar
    https://www.jitpack.io/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.pom
    https://www.jitpack.io/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.1/compiler-3.2.1.jar
Required by:
    project :app
```

Comment: What is the error message when the build fails?

Comment: You are missing `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_plugin_version"` in app/build.gradle dependencies section

Comment: I have edited the question adding the errors

Comment: I have managed to make it work downgrading the android plugin to 3.1.0 but I'm still wondering why it doesn't work with 3.2.1

Comment: I have faced the same issue here.. lost a day trying everything to solve it and it just worked for me when I downgraded the com.android.tools.build:gradle to 3.0.1.
I think it's a good idea to report this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54071510/1726296

> As of Android Studio 3.2, this kapt plugin is no longer required.

However, without this plug in, the error message in case of any error, while compiling is cryptic. 
So, only option now it seems now is to downgrade your Gradle version to 3.1.4.

Thanks to article at http://mobiledevhub.com/2018/01/05/android-two-way-databinding/