# Android : Error cannot find symbol @Nullable DatabindingComponent

Tags: android, binding

I'm getting this annoying error when I've updated to Android Studio 3.2.1 (Stable)

Although not all of the binding files were affected, only some of them.
I've checked out tutorials on data binding and also this link : [Cannot find symbol DataBindingComponent on Android Studio 3.2 Canary 16 Kotlin project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594507/cannot-find-symbol-databindingcomponent-on-android-studio-3-2-canary-16-kotlin-p)

But I wasn't able to find a solution, I created handlers for methods, set dataBinding to 'true' in the app gradle, also added `annotationProcessor "android.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.2.0-alpha10"`

I'm using Java (not Kotlin) in my project.
And my project uses the 'inflate' and 'setContentView' from the DataBinding class (without the DataBindingComponent option) but it still says `cannot find symbol class DataBindingComponent`

Example :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SPManager.save(this, SPManager.kIsChatActivityOpened, true);

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_chat);
    viewModel = new ChatActivityViewModel(binding, this);
    binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
```

Been stuck on this for awhile now and I can't get on with the project because I can't even build it.

Error :

```
{file path}.java:307: error: cannot find symbol
  @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
            ^ symbol:   class MyClass location: class MyBinding
```

Need help

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the Room Architectue Component as well?

I recently got the same error. First I thought it was a databinding issue, but then I figured out, that it was an error connected to the Room Architecture Component.

I have a class annotated as entity and added a field value, but forgot to provide getter and setter method for this. After i have done this, the error was gone.