# cannot find symbol class ActivityMainBinding

Tags: android, xml, android-databinding

I am facing with this problem related to a generated class for dataBinding. I couldn't figure this out.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Make sure to include all relevant code instead of the image. I think it might be a issue with it not being build properly. Please go to file InvalidateCaches and restart and see if it solves your problem

Comment: This can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594507/cannot-find-symbol-databindingcomponent-on-android-studio-3-2-canary-16-kotlin-p